# Decipher French General Name in 1792 Hessen War Campaign Diary

Tags: handwriting

I am trying to find out the name of the French General that is written in a 1792-93 Hessian Hussar war diary. The name looks like General Tüllon.  However, I cannot find any record of a general by that name.  The war diary mentions French Generals Kellermann and Dumouriez.
Any help is much appreciated.[image]

Comment: General François-Christophe Kellermann. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Army_of_the_Moselle.

Answer (score 6):

I'm reading the name as "Tüllon", too. Maybe [General Dillon](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Dillon_(General)) was meant?

Comment: Sounds plauisible. "After the Battle of Valmy, when Charles Dumouriez returned to the Belgian frontier with the greater part of the army, he detached Dillon with 16,000 troops to form the rump of the Army of the Ardennes around 1 October 1792." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Dillon_(1750%E2%80%931794)

Comment: Considering this was an English name pronounced by the French and then written down by a German, it's quite likely that you're right.

Comment: ... written down by a Hessian! These people say "Dudd" and write "Tüte". :-)

Comment: It's hard to say today who is to blame for the butchering of the name : My guess it that once it had gone through the French pronunciation mill, most of the damage had already been done ;).